# Problema com assinatura digital eSocial - Assinatura inválida

Tags: php, xml, api

Estou com problema na validação da assinatura o xml do eSocial. Já fizemos diversas tentativas, mas em todas o retorno do processamento do evento é o mesmo: "Assinatura do evento inválida. Ações Sugeridas: Verificar se houve alteração do evento após a assinatura. Verificar a validade da assinatura."

Gostaria de saber se alguém teve o mesmo problema e como resolveu. E se alguém sabe de algum problema referente a isso na ambiente de produção restrita do eSocial.

Segue abaixo xml assinado.

```html
<loteEventos>
 <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
  <envioLoteEventos grupo="2">
   <ideEmpregador>
    <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
    <nrInsc>99999999999999</nrInsc>
   </ideEmpregador>
   <ideTransmissor>
    <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
    <nrInsc>99999999999999</nrInsc>
   </ideTransmissor>
   <eventos>
    <evento Id="ID1999999999999992018011103585700001">
     <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabRubrica/v02_04_01">
      <evtTabRubrica Id="ID1999999999999992018011103585700001">
       <ideEvento>
        <tpAmb>3</tpAmb>
        <procEmi>1</procEmi>
        <verProc>V2.04.01</verProc>
       </ideEvento>
       <ideEmpregador>
        <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
        <nrInsc>99999999999999</nrInsc>
       </ideEmpregador>
       <infoRubrica>
        <inclusao>
         <ideRubrica>
          <codRubr>SGU-5</codRubr>
          <ideTabRubr>1</ideTabRubr>
          <iniValid>2018-01</iniValid>
          <fimValid>2018-12</fimValid>
         </ideRubrica>
         <dadosRubrica>
          <dscRubr>RUBRICA DESTINADA AO EVENTO 5-PRODUCAO PARA OS COOPERADOS.</dscRubr>
          <natRubr>3520</natRubr>
          <tpRubr>1</tpRubr>
          <codIncCP>15</codIncCP>
          <codIncIRRF>31</codIncIRRF>
          <codIncFGTS>00</codIncFGTS>
          <codIncSIND>00</codIncSIND>
          <observacao>RUBRICA DESTINADA AO EVENTO 5-PRODUCAO PARA OS COOPERADOS.</observacao>
          <ideProcessoIRRF>
           <nrProc>123</nrProc>
           <codSusp>0</codSusp>
          </ideProcessoIRRF>
         </dadosRubrica>
        </inclusao>
       </infoRubrica>
      </evtTabRubrica>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
       <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <Reference URI="">
         <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
         </Transforms>
         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
         <DigestValue>LH5RFX3/ftKopeifmwZCQPMx1yOSt7wR0yhxI6KAdgI=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
       </SignedInfo>
       <SignatureValue>M5VHtMjVpUWQprqvvVa+FcTUBhGjwunAElleqpIm72PmYnodnXegN7nBrPcTEGVcAdblQr0dJa+CMFssNjDGeWJy0A4VgJzsM/J5Cq3j80KPjLxJX7dK2oiVAeM4l+B/x507kSB7smaP/orPymB4a4NAAsBMPnweqyZYE02ZSJqN87PoBiu+OjFFjIuSE6zxApsceuP72Xpy+LtYKGvpZxRu1H810RzQxGdKA+VZ+22cw2H52W8bvRcXzhLpEoQN5IwNRiFK/R0jRMOQ81Jq/LZKhEqTRzvkdy76u1WoADxtfWcU2fN0iUo3i+H9Rw31ZEBWfb902D1dN07EBBlO5Q==</SignatureValue>
       <KeyInfo>
        <X509Data>
         <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
       </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
     </eSocial>
    </evento>
   </eventos>
  </envioLoteEventos>
 </eSocial>
</loteEventos>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../xmlseclibs-master/src/XMLSecurityDSig.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../xmlseclibs-master/src/XMLSecurityKey.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../xmlseclibs-master/src/XMLSecEnc.php';

$cabecalho_xml_evento='<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_04_01">';
$corpo_xml_evento='<evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1775187375501192018021417410600070"><ideEvento><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><procEmi>1</procEmi><verProc>1</verProc></ideEvento><ideEmpregador><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>99999999999999</nrInsc></ideEmpregador><infoEmpregador><inclusao><idePeriodo><iniValid>2018-01</iniValid></idePeriodo><infoCadastro><nmRazao>NOME DA EMPRESA</nmRazao><classTrib>85</classTrib><natJurid>1074</natJurid><indCoop>0</indCoop><indConstr>0</indConstr><indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha><indOptRegEletron>0</indOptRegEletron><indEntEd>N</indEntEd><indEtt>N</indEtt><contato><nmCtt>Nome do Contato</nmCtt><cpfCtt>123456789</cpfCtt><foneFixo>123456789</foneFixo><foneCel>123456789</foneCel><email>123@de.oliveira.quatro</email></contato><infoOP><nrSiafi>12345</nrSiafi></infoOP><softwareHouse><cnpjSoftHouse>123456789</cnpjSoftHouse><nmRazao>NOME DA SFOTWAREHOUSE</nmRazao><nmCont>Nome do Contato</nmCont><telefone>123456789</telefone><email>123@de.oliveira.quatro</email></softwareHouse><infoComplementares><situacaoPJ><indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ></situacaoPJ></infoComplementares></infoCadastro></inclusao></infoEmpregador></evtInfoEmpregador>';
$rodape_xml_evento='</eSocial>';

//Assinar evento
$objEventoDOMDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$objEventoDOMDoc->loadXML($cabecalho_xml_evento.$corpo_xml_evento.$rodape_xml_evento);
$objXMLSecurityDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig(FALSE);
$objXMLSecurityDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);
$objXMLSecurityDSig->addReference(
  $objEventoDOMDoc, 
  XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256,
  array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature','http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'),
  array("force_uri"=>true)
);
$objXMLSecurityKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA256, array('type'=>'private'));
$objXMLSecurityKey->passphrase = 'senha_chave_privada';
$objXMLSecurityKey->loadKey('/path_para_chave_PEM_privada', TRUE);
$objXMLSecurityDSig->sign($objXMLSecurityKey);
$objXMLSecurityDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents('/path_para_chave_PEM_publica'));
$objXMLSecurityDSig->appendSignature($objEventoDOMDoc->documentElement);
$objSimpleXMLElement = simplexml_import_dom($objEventoDOMDoc);
$assinatura_xml_evento = $objSimpleXMLElement->Signature->asXml();

//Montar lote  
$lote_xml = '<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1"><envioLoteEventos grupo="1"><ideEmpregador><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>99999999999999</nrInsc></ideEmpregador><ideTransmissor><tpInsc>2</tpInsc><nrInsc>48699999999</nrInsc></ideTransmissor><eventos><evento Id="ID1775187375501192018021417410600070">'.
$cabecalho_xml_evento.$corpo_xml_evento.$assinatura_xml_evento.$rodape_xml_evento
'</evento></eventos></envioLoteEventos></eSocial>';

//Transmitir lote
$strXmlAEnviar = '<EnviarLoteEventos><loteEventos>' . $lote_xml . '</loteEventos></EnviarLoteEventos>';
$params = array(
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        "trace" => 1,
        'cache_wsdl' => 0,
        'connection_timeout' => 25,
        "exceptions" => true,
        "style" => SOAP_RPC,
        "use" => SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'local_cert' => '/path_para_chaves_PEM_privada_e_publica_combinadas_em_um_unico_arquivo',
        'passphrase' => 'senha_chave_privada',
    );

$client = new SoapClient('https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl', $params);
$paramSoapCall = new SoapVar($strXmlAEnviar, XSD_ANYXML);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance','xsi');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','xsd');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope','soap');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
$response = $client->EnviarLoteEventos($paramSoapCall);

//Processar retorno do envio
$strXmlRetorno = $response->EnviarLoteEventosResult->any;
```

[Biblioteca PHP para assinatura digital de arquivos xml](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs)

Comment: Seria legal você incluir uma breve descrição de como exatamente esse script resolve a questão da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Mayara, qual trecho do XML você usou para gerar a assinatura? Você deve assinar apenas o XML do evento, e não o XML do lote, então, você deve assinar apenas o trecho que começa com a segunda tag 'eSocial' (rubrica), até o fechamento da mesma.

Também, não deveria existir essa tag inicial 'loteEventos', e o grupo, na tag 'envioLoteEventos', deveria ser 1 e não 2, no caso do evento de rubricas (S-1010).

Eu criei uma página há um tempo atrás com alguns exemplos de arquivos XML do eSocial. Ela está defasada, e todos os exemplos são da versão 2.2.02 do leiaute (e não da última versão, 2.4.01), mas, dá para ter uma ideia:
http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/ExemplosEventosXml.htm#S1010

Espero que ajude.