# assinatura digital em arquivos xml para o e-social

Tags: php, api

Olá, preciso sanar a duvida quanto a assinatura no envio do xml para o e-social, veja estou me baseando do artigo [Problema com assinatura digital eSocial - Assinatura inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270113/problema-com-assinatura-digital-esocial-assinatura-inv%C3%A1lida) tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

```
$objXMLSecurityDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents('/path_para_chave_PEM_publica'));
```

Essa chave seria o que exatamente? Vem da cadeia de certificados que o e-social pede para ser instalado na maquina que vai fazer o acesso?

A mesma duvida se aplica aqui

`$objXMLSecurityKey->loadKey('/path_para_chave_PEM_privada', TRUE);`

Sendo que em outro caso tenho o seguinte:

```
'local_cert' => '/path_para_chaves_PEM_privada_e_publica_combinadas_em_um_unico_arquivo',
```

isso me deixou com mais dúvidas, tem que esta configurado chave pública e privada num único arquivo?

Utiliza a biblioteca [Biblioteca PHP para assinatura digital de arquivos xml](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei PHP, e nunca tinha visto a biblioteca **XMLSecLibs** do **RobRichards**, mas, também estou desenvolvendo para o eSocial (.NET) e sei alguma coisa do procedimento de como assinar os eventos e como se comunicar ao serviço, então, tentarei ajudar.

Você disse que está com dúvida nesses 3 trechos, com relação ao certificado:

```
$objXMLSecurityDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents('/path_para_chave_PEM_publica'));

$objXMLSecurityKey->loadKey('/path_para_chave_PEM_privada', TRUE);

'local_cert' => '/path_para_chaves_PEM_privada_e_publica_combinadas_em_um_unico_arquivo',
```

O eSocial exige um certificado digital **A1** ou **A3**, tanto para assinar os eventos quanto para se comunicar com o serviço. No Windows, o certificado A1 normalmente vem num arquivo **.pfx**, que contém a chave pública e a chave privada, e você pode instalar esse arquivo no Windows e usa-lo do repositório de certificados do Windows, ou abrir o arquivo diretamente. No meu caso sempre estou pegando o certificado instalado no repositório do Windows.

Como disse, não conheço a biblioteca **XMLSecLibs**, então não sei dizer se ela aceita diretamente um arquivo **.pfx** ou se ela aceita somente arquivos **.pem**, mas, eu fiz uma pesquisa rápida e descobri que os arquivos **.pem** também podem armazenar a chave pública e a chave privada, como o arquivo **.pfx**, e, é possível converter um arquivo do formato **.pfx** para o formato **.pem**.

Seguem alguns links que explicam melhor isso:

> Resumo sobre Certificado Digital - Base de Conhecimento
>   http://fantastsoft.com.br/basecon/base-conhecimento/resumo-sobre-certificado-digital/
>
> SEGURANÇA, Quais são as diferenças entre os certificados PEM, DER, P7B / PKCS # 7, PFX / PKCS # 12?
>   https://discursa.rknet.top/t/seguranca-quais-sao-as-diferencas-entre-os-certificados-pem-der-p7b-pkcs-7-pfx-pkcs-12/258
>
> Conversão de certificado CA (TIPO A1) de PFX para PEM
>   https://www.rafaeltheodoro.com.br/nfe/conversao-de-certificado-ca-tipo-a1-de-pfx-para-pem/

Então eu creio que você possa pegar um **certificado digital A1** válido no formato **.pfx** e converte-lo para um arquivo **.pem**, como nos exemplos dos links (usando algum aplicativo **OpenSSL**):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificado.pfx -out certificado.pem –nodes
```

Feito isso eu imagino que você possa usar esse arquivo **certificado.pem** em todas as 3 linhas que você estava com dúvida, porque ele conterá a chave pública e a chave privada do seu certificado A1, e é o seu certificado A1 que é necessário para assinar os eventos do eSocial e para abrir a comunicação com o serviço do eSocial (as duas primeiras linhas de dúvida se referem à assinatura, e a terceira se refere à transmissão).

Esse certificado usado para a assinatura deve ter o mesmo CNPJ raiz do empregador cujos eventos estão sendo assinados (ou CPF), ou pode ser outro CNPJ/CPF desde que você tenha feito uma procuração eletrônica no site **e-CAC** da Receita Federal.

Comment: Amigo Pedro Gaspar, em cima disso, me gerou outras dúvidas, por exemplo, somente o A1 gera o arquivo pfx?
No sistema que vai acessaro eSocial, eu por exemplo vou manda dados de varias empresas, nesse caso, eu teria que ter um A1 para cada empresa que eu tiver que enviar os dados para o eSocial?

Comment: Então Edson, se você precisa assinar os eventos de outras empresas, ou seja, você vai assinar em nome delas, ou você precisa ter o certificado dessas empresas em mãos, ou, como eu disse no final da resposta, você precisa que essas empresas cadastrem uma procuração eletrônica na Receita Federal, que vai permitir que você assine eventos para o eSocial em nome delas. No site do eSocial tem um passo-a-passo sobre procuração eletrônica: http://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/orientacoes-assinatura-digital-e-procuracao-eletronica

Comment: Edson, você conseguiu usar a biblioteca *XMLSecLibs* para assinar os arquivos XML em PHP? Se sim, você chegou a testar se ela aceita diretamente o certificado digital com extensão *.pfx*? Se puder poste aqui essa informação, porque pode ajudar outros com o mesmo problema!

Comment: Não Pedro, não consegui mesmo, estou tentando até agora fazer isso, mas estou com problemas sérios em entender isso, por isso minha demora em retornar

Comment: Mas está dando algum erro? Qualquer coisa posta uma nova pergaunta com os detalhes, se for algum problema diferente do que você perguntou aqui.

Comment: Ta meio complicado entender isso, vou fazer um apanhado geral para poder colocar melhor as duvidas aqui